# python pptx: How to check if text in two placeholders overlap

Tags: python, python-pptx

I'm using python-pptx to create a presentation.

I have a slide with 2 Text placeholders, the 1st above the 2nd (the same x-coord (shape.left)). When I put the text in both, the text in the 1st shape is long and overlap the text in the shape below. If I find out that there is the overlap, I can move the 1st shape (text) up or move the 2nd text down. But how to check the overlap?

Or how to get height of text in placeholder/text box? (then I can calculate vertical size and find overlap).

The python is preferred language but the package can be any, so you can suggest any package if it can solve it.

I can provide some code if needed.

EDIT: Yes, I'm looking for a solution in python (regardless package).
Code example:

```
import time
from pptx import Presentation as pptx_Presentation
from pptx.enum.text import MSO_AUTO_SIZE

def get_date_time_str():
    """Return string of "now" in %Y%m%d-%H%M%S format"""
    return time.strftime("%Y%m%d-%H%M%S", time.localtime())

long_text = "F" * 60
empty = r"C:\f\empty.pptx"  # PowerPoint file where is "Sections" layout and no slide
new = pptx_Presentation(empty)

slide_layout = new.slide_layouts[1]
# there are 2 Text Placeholders, both have the same shape.left so they are one above another

# Example 1: Set text directly into text_frame
slide1 = new.slides.add_slide(slide_layout)
for shape in slide1.shapes:
    shape.text_frame.text = long_text

# Example 2: Set text in paragraphs
# 3 paragraphs for each Text Placeholder
# NOTE: sometimes I also set text in runs in paragraphs
slide2 = new.slides.add_slide(slide_layout)
pars_data = [long_text for i in [1,2,3]]
wrap = True # False

for shape in slide2.shapes:
    text_frame = shape.text_frame
    text_frame.word_wrap = wrap
    # also tested setting 'auto_size' before putting text
    # text_frame.auto_size = MSO_AUTO_SIZE.SHAPE_TO_FIT_TEXT
    text_frame.paragraphs[0].text = pars_data[0]

    for par_data in pars_data[1:]:
        par = text_frame.add_paragraph()
        par.text = par_data

    text_frame.auto_size = MSO_AUTO_SIZE.SHAPE_TO_FIT_TEXT

date_str = get_date_time_str()
out = rf"C:\f\out-{date_str}.pptx"
new.save(out)
```

Comment: It would be very nice if @scanny cound check this question.

Comment: Please share the Python code you're asking about - currently this is a question about PowerPoint and it's unclear how Python would relate to it (other than you asking for a Python solution)

Comment: OK, with `python-pptx` installed and an empty presentation created and saved from PowerPoint as `empty.pptx`, your code runs and the problem is apparent. However, there are two issues: you're using some sort of layout, that sets the position of the text elements you're using, and the elements don't resize in response to the changes the library makes. If you open the document in PowerPoint, you'll find that a single edit will cause the element to resize, but the overlap remains. You should try doing what you're looking to do from Python manually first, figure out what the desired result is.

Comment: Text tends to overflow placeholders / shapes anyway. So the dimensions are no real guarantee of anything.

Comment: If text overflows - how to find it out? How to check it if it happened?